# How to i make this slideshow auto playable

Tags: javascript, blogger

I'm having problem to make an autoplay slideshow.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var owl = $("#owl-wrapper");
 owl.owlCarousel({
  items: 8,
  itemsDesktop: [1000, 8],
  itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 6],
  itemsTablet: [600, 4],
  itemsMobile: false,
  navigation: false
 });
 $(".next").click(function() {
  owl.trigger('owl.next');
 })
 $(".prev").click(function() {
  owl.trigger('owl.prev');
 })
});
```

now im facing to add autoplay function

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
var owl = $("#owl-wrapper");
owl.owlCarousel({items:8,itemsDesktop:[1000,8],itemsDesktopSmall:[900,6],itemsTablet:[600,4],itemsMobile:false,navigation:false}); 
// Custom Navigation Events
$(".next").click(function(){owl.trigger('owl.next');})
$(".prev").click(function(){owl.trigger('owl.prev');})
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var owl = $("#owl-wrapper");
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 8,
    itemsDesktop: [1000, 8],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 6],
    itemsTablet: [600, 4],
    itemsMobile: false,
    navigation: false,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:1000, // set this to how long you want spent between slides
  });
  $(".next").click(function() {
    owl.trigger('owl.next');
  })
  $(".prev").click(function() {
    owl.trigger('owl.prev');
  })
});
```

By default autoPlay is `false` which is why you have to set it. You can read more about it [here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html)

Comment: Even though  it doesn't work. https://www.anitracksub.com/ Here i tried the codings.